# How to add a invisible anchor in the front of `span`?

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

**Constraint:** Support IE7.

---

**Description:**

There are lots of `<span class="sentence">` in my webpage. I'd like to add a tooltip **at the beginning of `.sentence`** when user clicks on a `.sentence`.

```
var $tooltip = $('<span id="tooltip-anchor"></span>').html(
                 $('<input type="button" class="tooltip" id="sentence-tooltip">'));
$('.sentence.select').prepend($tooltip);
$tooltip.hide().fadeIn(200);
```

The structure will become:

```
<span class="sentence">
  <span id="tooltip-anchor"> <!-- Anchors at the beginning of sentence.-->
    <input type="button" class="tooltip" id="sentence-tooltip"> <!-- The tooltip -->
  </span>
  text text
</span>
```

But this method has a problem: when the `.sentence` starts at the left border of browser, the `span#tooltip-anchor` appears at the right border of browser, because the browser breaks the line between `#tooltip-anchor` and the `.sentence.select`. How can I fix this problem?

`#tooltip-anchor` is just an idea I thought to anchor the beginning of the `.sentence`. Can you help come up with another solution?

---

**Expect:**

- The tooltip is floating on the top of the beginning of the sentence.
- The tooltip feature should not change the layout of sentences.

  ```
                      [tooltip]
  This is a sentence. This is
  another sentence.
  ```

---

**Code:**
JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5x7s1org/2/)

```js
$.fn.extend({
  deselectSentence: function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('select')) {
      $('#sentence-tooltip').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
      $(this).removeClass('select');
    }
  },
  selectSentence: function() {
    $('.sentence.refresh.select').each(function() {
      $(this).deselectSentence();
    });
    var $tooltip = $('<span id="tooltip-anchor"></span>').html(
      $('<input type="button" class="tooltip" id="sentence-tooltip">'));
    $(this).prepend($tooltip);
    $tooltip.hide().fadeIn(200);

    $(this).addClass('select');
  }
});
$('.sentence.refresh').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('select')) {
    $(this).deselectSentence();
  } else {
    $(this).selectSentence();
  }
});
```

```css
.sentence.refresh {
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.sentence.refresh:hover {
  background-color: #cde5fe;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.sentence.refresh.select {
  background-color: #96cbff;
  border-color: #bbb;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  background: url(Images/search.png) no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
  top: -30px;
}
.tooltip:hover {
  border-color: #96cbff;
  background-color: #96cbff;
}
#tooltip-anchor {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:200px">
  <span class="sentence refresh">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text. </span>
  <span
  class="sentence refresh">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text. </span>
    <span
    class="sentence refresh">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span>
      <span
      class="sentence refresh">short text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span>
        <span
        class="sentence refresh">short text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span>
          <span
          class="sentence refresh">short text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span>
            <span
            class="sentence refresh">short text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span>
              <span
              class="sentence refresh">short text.</span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span><span class="sentence refresh">short text. </span>
                </body>
```

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` ?

Comment: In HTML, ids should always be unique identifiers. That means there should never be more than one tag on a page with id "tooltip-anchor".

Comment: You might consider using the ::before css selector for this.

Comment: `select` `class` not appear at `html` ?

Comment: @onsmith Thanks. But I just want keep one tooltip show at each time. An old tooltip will be removed before a new tooltip is added. Anyway, it's not the main issue.

Comment: @YuvalA. Thanks. Unfortunately I need to support the antediluvian browser IE7 which doesn't support ::before. Nor do I want to use ie-css3.htc which causes some weird problem now and then.

Comment: @guest271314 It's just `background-color` and such css. Not important.

Comment: the funny thing is that jsfiddle doesn't support IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is wrong in IE7. I inserted `.tooltip-anchor` using jQuery which added inline style "zoom: 1; display: inline". **It is the "zoom: 1" that causes possible line breaks between `.tooltip-anchor` and trailing text.**

The css is modified as follows:

```
.tooltip-anchor {
    position: relative;
    *zoom: 0 !important; /* <--- Added */
}
```

And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the css `position` stuff, and changed the tooltip to show on click, just to get an idea of what it would look like.  This doesn't appear to have the problem you are mentioning.

It could definitely be cleaned up, but it gives you a starting place and I believe it corrects your current issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $tooltip = $('<span id="tooltip-anchor"></span>').html(
                 $('<input type="button" class="tooltip" id="sentence-tooltip" value="?" />'));
  $tooltip.hide();
  $('.sentence').prepend($tooltip).on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('#tooltip-anchor').fadeIn(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
        /*position: absolute;*/
        z-index: 9999;
        border: solid 1px #bbb;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline; *zoom: 1; /* IE7 inline-block fix */
        background: url(Images/search.png) no-repeat;
        background-color: #fff;
        position:absolute;
        top:-30px;
    }

#tooltip-anchor{
  position:relative;
    
}
```

```html
<!-- some line breaks so the tooltip will have room to display. -->
sample text-- don't click here. This just shows that the elements above the tooltip don't shift.
<br /><br />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="sentence">
  click this text to see a tool tip.
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want the tooltip floating above the beginning of the sentence. Also your method will push the sentence backward. I want the layout of sentences to be stable.

Comment: In IE7 this code is problematic. Repro: type really long text into `.sentence`, click the long sentence, the tooltip will be added but the long sentence is pushed to the 2nd line.